# how to choose aggregate root

Tags: domain-driven-design, aggregate

I model three entities in the auto industry as following:

```
public class Manufacturer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Model> Models { get; set; }
    public ACManufacturer()
    {
        AutoCareModels = new List<ACModel>();
    }
}

public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
    public int NumberOfSeats { get; set; }
    public Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ManufacturedYear> ManufacturedYears { get; set; }     
    public Model()
    {
        ManufacturedYears = new List<ManufacturedYear>();
    }
 }

public class ManufacturedYear
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ProductionYear { get; set; }
    public Model Model { get; set; }
}
```

Please tell me how to choose aggregate root or the differente way to model three entities

Thank you every much

Answer (score 0):

Answer depends on what you do with these models. What is your app doing? If 10 users are updating data in this app - how can they divide their work? What are transaction boundaries? 
If those 10 users are usually working with 10 different models, your screens are organized around models, then Model is your aggregate root.

Comment: Thank for your reply. 


In the app, three entities above are used as referenced entities and I  is currently selecting the manufacture the aggregate root. So when I load a manufacture, I also have to load

Comment: Thank for your reply. If I select Model as an aggregate root, then the Manufacture will come an aggregate root? In the app I have been making, three entities above are used as referenced entities and I is currently selecting the Manufacture the aggregate root. Can you tell me if this is right or not?

If the model become more deeply, what is the suitable way to select the aggregate?